# Sent text by bank I don’t have an account with- Is this a scam?

Tags: scam

I have received this text message supposedly from NatWest bank (UK), yet I have never had an account with them or given away details to them:

> Our team have tried to contact you regarding your online account.
>   Login via the secure link http:// 103.208.86.131 to avoid account suspension.

I looked up the location of the given IP and it said it originated from New Zealand. Is this a virus or other sort of scam?

Comment: I posted a question related to your question, in case you're curious:
https://security.stackexchange.com/q/193677/149676

Comment: 1- Poor spelling = Sender is unfamiliar to the language = Not likely authentic. 2- Using IP instead DNS = sender does not have access to the bank website = fake. 3- saying http is secure = Huge lie = Sender has wrong/criminal intentions. 4- We are gonna suspend your account = FUD = Too agresive to be true/legit... In summary, looks like clasic scam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a scam. You don't have an account there, so why would they have your email or phone number? And why host a business critical process on a no-domain address without even using HTTPS? And calling it a *secure link*? Lots of red flags...

If you open that site, the site will probably use a exploit kit to download and execute malware, or show a convincing login page to make you disclose your credentials.

Usually banks don't send emails or text messages to clients regarding account suspension, email and SMS are not the trusted ways to do so.

Comment: It was my personal phone number that this Text message was sent to, not my email

Comment: Notice how it says "Our team have tried... " and not "Dear Boolean, our team have tried..." That message is sent to millions of phone numbers. Check the message. You won't find anything that indicates they know who you are.

Comment: I would also mention the FUD, it is often used by scammers to make targets act before asking themselves about the actual content of the message.