# Spam link returns empty redirect to google.com - am I missing something?

Tags: http, spam

In [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193673/sent-text-by-bank-i-don-t-have-an-account-with-is-this-a-scam) someone received what was clearly a spam link.  Sometimes I'm curious enough to take a peek, which I usually do with curl or other command line tools (less risk of drive-by malware, although I'm on linux so I'm not usually susceptible to most such attacks).  I got this as the response from the website:

```
curl -v 'http://103.208.86.131/'
*   Trying 103.208.86.131...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 103.208.86.131 (103.208.86.131) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 103.208.86.131
> User-Agent: curl/7.56.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2018 18:27:16 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.25
< Location: https://www.google.com
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host 103.208.86.131 left intact
```

It doesn't return an actual response, but rather just a 302 redirect to google.com.  It doesn't even set a cookie.  From what I can tell it literally just returns a simple redirect to google.  This left me mildly confused as to what the actual purpose of this is.  Obviously scammers have their own technical problems, so this could be a sign of a screw up (or perhaps they shut down their actual pages for whatever reason), but I can't help but wonder if perhaps:

1. There is something else to this request/response that I'm missing?
2. There is a reason (other than "oops") why a spam link might return nothing but an empty redirect?

Obviously my IP Address is potentially now in their server logs, but I can't imagine they were just trolling for IP addresses...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first guess was the site was probably using your User Agent string to identify if you are vulnerable or not. As you are using `curl` and not changing the UserAgent, the exploit kit would redirect you to a harmless page.

I used `curl` with an IE11 UserAgent string, and got the same redirect. Probably my IP is not on the list of desired ones.

Next guess: IP address.

The IP address is usually matched against a list of desired targets, usually tied to a country. It is usually meant to keep the exploit kit secret and only expose it to the interesting targets, avoiding it to be readily flagged by security companies.

So I tried again using an UK proxy:

```
http_proxy=88.211.x.x:8080 curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko' -v 'http://103.208.86.131/'
*   Trying 88.211.x.x...
* Connected to 88.211.x.x (88.211.x.x) port 8080 (#0)
> GET http://103.208.86.131/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 103.208.86.131
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2018 18:48:47 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.25
< Location: index2.php?&sessionid=08bcaee2029a8a766175c5c8cebc8bff&securessl=true
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host 88.211.x.x left intact
```

And it connected, redirected me to another page.

Comment: Well that's not fun.  I don't suppose you happen to have a VPN endpoint in the UK?

Comment: :) That was not actually a serious request

Comment: I don't have a VPN, but a search for "open UK proxy list" returned a couple ones. The site ends up redirecting to a Russian website after a couple hops.

Comment: Sneaky sneaky...  index2.php doesn't do the fancy IP address check, so I get a curl response out of that one directly (contains an HTML redirect to Login.php)